# MongoDB on with Docker "failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: node-mongo
    env_file:
        "./NodeJs/.env"
    restart: always
    image: style-app
    build:
      context: ./NodeJs
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8083:6017'
    external_links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontstyle
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: "front-style-frontend"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - "app:be"
```

inside `.env`

```
MONGOURI=mongodb://mongo:27017/mydb
```

inside `app.js`

```
var mongoDB = process.env.MONGOURI;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true})
```

I don't know why this is not connecting correctly if I create image for mongo then I run docker-compose up it says already The container name `"/mongo"` is already in use by container.

Please guide

Comment: I think MONGOURI should be mongodb://mongo:27017/mydb

Comment: Deleting the explicit `container_name:` might help avoid conflicts; you also shouldn't need to create a MongoDB image or container separate from this Compose setup.

Comment: I think I have the same string isn't ?

Comment: @DavidMaze this one is helpful

Comment: Now I have container

2450d1e6a56d   mongo              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago

docker exec -it mongo bash
Why Error: No such container: mongo

Comment: @DavidMaze  so are you saying not to create mongodb and container image inside docker-compose.yml file ?

Comment: _Do_ include it in `docker-compose.yml`.  You can use `docker-compose` equivalents of plain `docker` commands if you do need things like debugging shells or to directly manipulate containers, but these should be unusual.  (If you started MongoDB directly on your host, how would you get a shell inside of it?)

Comment: Okay thanks, Please explain that part Now I have container 2450d1e6a56d mongo "docker-entrypoint.s…" 2 minutes ago docker exec -it mongo bash Why Error: No such container: mongo –

Comment: here mongo is the name of the image, and not the container's name.